# Query to find all dates within an interval which are missing from my table

Tags: mysql, date

I need to pick up all the dates in a given interval that are not in a table.

Example table dates has

```
2012-09-24
2012-09-26
```

My given date interval is `2012-09-23` to `2012-09-27`

My query should return

```
2012-09-23
2012-09-25
2012-09-27
```

Can anyone give me some hints as to how to go about this? I've searched a lot but haven't found anything on this problem.

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://www.whathaveyoutried.com/) See [ask advice](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask-advice), please.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest solution is to construct a calendar table storing all possible dates and then compare against that.

Comment: That's an interesting approach. I thought of creating views on the fly and using that to compare but thought it wouldn't be very efficient. Your idea is similar but more efficient.